# Пункты меню в PHPStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, отладка, xdebug, настройки

На [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5) приведены следующие пункты меню

- выбираем `Web server is installed locally, source files are located under its document root`
- выбираем папку с файлами, и нажав вверху кнопку "Project Root" помечаем папку как корень проекта
- нажимаем "Next"
- нажимаем Add new local server

Где они находятся (у меня версия PHPStorm 2021.1)?

Comment: в приветственном окне шторма, до запуска IDE (то есть целиком интерфейса программы)

Comment: а приветственное окно шторма исчезло с момента первого запуска программы. Где можно найти эти настройки в интерфейсе программы? @Jean-Claude

Comment: Можно закрыть проект File -> Close Project

Comment: если проект уже запущен, то просто пропусти это шаг)) он же, ПРОЕКТ! уже создан!